# Boxlayout can't be shared AWTError... recorrecting my previous quest which had Nullpointerexception am getting this error.. Please help me out

Tags: java, swing, boxlayout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please help me to sort out this java.awt.BoxLayout can't be shared or NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597427/please-help-me-to-sort-out-this-java-awt-boxlayout-cant-be-shared-or-nullpointe)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: BoxLayout can't be shared
at javax.swing.BoxLayout.checkContainer(BoxLayout.java:445)
at javax.swing.BoxLayout.invalidLayout(BoxLayout.java:229)
at javax.swing.BoxLayout.addLayoutComponent(BoxLayout.java:262)
at javax.awt.Container.addImpl(JFrame.java: 1068)
at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java: 935)
at javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(JFrame.java: 545)
at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java: 352)
at BoxExample.launchFrame(BoxExample.java:26)
at BoxExample.main(BoxExample.java:40)
```

The code after editing my own previously published post named:
"Please help me to sort out this java.awt.BoxLayout can't be shared or NullPointerException"

if you are new to this post also, please look into the code and solve for me:

```
//Boxlayout

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class BoxExample
{
public JFrame f;
public JButton b1, b2,b3,b4,b5;

public BoxExample()
{
f=new JFrame("Box example");
f.setTitle("Box Layout Example");
f.setSize(150, 150);
b1=new JButton("Button 1");
b2=new JButton("Button 2");
b3=new JButton("Button 3");
b4=new JButton("Button 4");
b5=new JButton("Button 5");
}

public void launchFrame()
{
System.out.println("inside lf");
f.setLayout(new BoxLayout(f,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
System.out.println("after layset");
f.add(b1);
f.add(b2);
f.add(b3);
f.add(b4);
f.add(b5);
f.pack();
f.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
BoxExample guiWindow=new BoxExample();
System.out.println("main");
guiWindow.launchFrame();
}
}
```

Comment: You literally asked this 40 minutes ago. Look at [@HovercraftFullOfEel](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11597449/758280)'s answer and provide the code he asked for (there is an edit button at the bottom of your question, so you can amend your first question instead of asking another).

Comment: oops.. thats ok.. but i heard it too late :) anyway.. thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

`BoxLayout` cannot be shared, there is a conflict, as the buttons are added to frame's content pane, but the layout is initialized with frame as a target. To fix, replace this:

```
f.setLayout(new BoxLayout(f,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

with:

```
f.setLayout(new BoxLayout(f.getContentPane(),BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

Comment: though i give the above.. am getting only the same kind of obstacle... anyway dude.. i tried the previous suggestion by you: "public void launchFrame() {
    System.out.println("inside lf");
    JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
    buttonPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonPane,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    System.out.println("after layset");
    buttonPane.add(b1);
    buttonPane.add(b2);
    buttonPane.add(b3);
    buttonPane.add(b4);
    buttonPane.add(b5);
    f.add(buttonPane);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
}" which works well.. but may i know wat could be the reason behind it..?

Comment: huh.. that was my mistake in running the above.. sorry Max the above also did work well..!!!

Comment: The suggested fix should also work. But you can use separate panel as well. `BoxLayout` makes sure that the layout methods are applied to the correct container. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10868110/1048330) for more details.